# What does this ImportError mean when importing my c++ module?

Tags: python, c++

I've been working on writing a Python module in C++. I have a C++ [program](https://github.com/justinrixx/Asteroids2.0/blob/master/gameNNRunner.cpp) that can run on its own. It works great, but I thought it would be better if I could actually call it like a function from Python. So I took my best go at it, and it builds and installs. Here's the code for my module (called nnrunner.cpp):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <vector>
#include "game.h"
#include "neuralnetai.h"

using namespace std;

/**************************************************
 * This is the actual function that will be called
 *************************************************/
static int run(string filename)
{
    srand(clock());
    Game * pGame = new Game();

    vector<int> topology;
    topology.push_back(20);

    Network net(31, 4, topology);

    net.fromFile(filename);

    NNAI ai(pGame, net);

    pGame->setAI(&ai);

    while (!pGame->isGameOver())
        pGame->update(NULL);

    return pGame->getScore();
}

static PyObject *
nnrunner_run(PyObject * self, PyObject * args)
{
    string filename;
    int score;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &filename))
        return NULL;
    score = run(filename);
    return PyLong_FromLong(score);
}

static PyMethodDef NnrunnerMethods[] = {
        {"run",  nnrunner_run, METH_VARARGS,
         "Run the game and return the score"},
        {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

static struct PyModuleDef nnrunnermodule = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        "nnrunner",   /* name of module */
        NULL, /* module documentation, may be NULL */
        -1,       /* size of per-interpreter state of the module,
                or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables. */
        NnrunnerMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_nnrunner(void)
{
    PyObject *m;

    m = PyModule_Create(&nnrunnermodule);
    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return m;
}
```

And my build script (called setup.py):

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('nnrunner',
                    sources = ['nnrunner.cpp', 'game.cpp', 'uiDraw.cpp', 
                    'uiInteract.cpp', 'player.cpp', 'ship.cpp', 'network.cpp'],
                    libraries = ['glut', 'GL', 'GLU'])

setup (name = 'NNRunner',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'This is my first package',
       ext_modules = [module1])
```

It has to compile with `-lglut -lGL -lGLU` due to a dependency, but it doesn't actually have any UI.
I can compile it and install it (`python setup.py build`, `python setup.py install`) but when I try to import it, I get errors:

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nnrunner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/justin/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nnrunner.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
>>>
```

Could somebody point me in the direction of documentation about this? This is the first time I've tried to make a Python module in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it means that you're importing a shared library that has a binary interface not compatible with your Python distribution.

So in your case: You have a 64-bit Python, and you're importing a 32-bit library, or vice-versa. (Or as suggested in a comment, a different compiler is used).

Comment: Or perhaps a different compiler. This happens often when compiling C on OS X.

Comment: I know I have a 64-bit Python interpreter. So for clarity, you're saying that perhaps the `<vector>` that I'm including is 32-bit, or perhaps some other library like that is 32-bit? How would I go about figuring out if a particular library is 32 or 64-bit? Or that it was compiled with a different compiler than what my Python build script uses?

Comment: @justinrixx No. I'm saying that the compiler that you're using produces 32-bit binaries. This is one possibility. One other possibility is that the compiler that produced the Anaconda executable is not the same compiler that produced your lib file. Try to import your library to the standard Python that comes with your Linux distribution. What Linux distribution are you using? If Debian/Ubuntu, install Python with `sudo apt-get install python3`, and then run `python3` and import your module, and see what happens.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Yes I'm using Ubuntu. I get the same error when I use `python3` that I got with Anaconda. When I ran `python setup.py build` it ran some g++ stuff. But shouldn't the `.so` that's built be the same architecture as the default interpreter (which I think is Anaconda)?

Comment: @justinrixx Anaconda is a distribution of Python. Try to install the native Python that comes with your Ubuntu. Honestly, I don't understand why you would ever need Anaconda on Ubuntu, but anyway, we have to make sure that you understand that Anaconda is a foreign distribution of Python on your operating system, and is possibly compiled with a different compiler. I need you to try to import your library on the *native Python* of your operating system. It should be located in `/usr/bin/Python3` (or similar).

Comment: I installed Anaconda so I could get all the sklearn libraries and numpy and stuff bundled together. But yeah so if I do the build and install with `/usr/bin/python` I can import it just fine. So I guess you were exactly right about it being some kind of a compiler issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

had similar problem with [multivec's](https://github.com/eske/multivec) cython module. i'm guessing there's incompatibility issue on between compiler and Anaconda library.

solved it by upgrading the Anaconda `libgcc` package: `conda install libgcc`